# Restricting sound control

Tags: linux, audio, account-restrictions

I need to restrict users so that they cannot output sound from built-in speakers. They should plug their headphones to hear any sound. They should be able to control headphone volume level, but not built-in speakers.

I need a command-line solution for automation purposes.

Is this possible (on Ubuntu 12.04)?

Comment: Are the speakers and headphones on separate channels?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: with current hardware: yes, this is pretty common. Not sure how it exactly works, but I think it is basically supported by multiple sound cards (which cost next to nothing nowadays when integrated in the motherboard).

Comment: @jippie: Except the driver can override this, switching between them as headphones are plugged in. So while the hardware may support it, the configuration may not.

Comment: I think that is exactly the problem with solving this question.

Comment: That requires some drivers i guess .. but OpenBSD seems to have the ability to detect if a Jack is plugged in